# Spring Data Cassandra Query DSL RxJava2

Tags: java, spring, rx-java2, querydsl, spring-data-cassandra

So I am using Spring Data Cassandra and RxJava, I am looking for a way to use RxJava Observable with custom query building (the find..by abstraction is to complicated to use in my case) and I was planning on using QueryDSL (the method findAll(Predicate), but it does not enable Async :/)

So far my best shot is to use AsyncCassandraTemplate to build a Query and return it as ListenableFuture so that it can be mapped to a Observable and be used with RxJava's Observable. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no QueryDsl support Spring Data for Apache Cassandra. You can use [`Query`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/cassandra/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/cassandra/core/query/Query.html) objects to create queries and [`ReactiveCassandraTemplate`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/cassandra/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/cassandra/core/ReactiveCassandraTemplate.html) for reactive API usage:

```
Mono<Person> person = cassandraTemplate.selectOneById(query(where("age").is(33)), Person.class);
Maybe<Person> maybe = Flowable.fromPublisher(person).firstElement();
```

Comment: Seems like the rigth way to go; the documentation mentions is though https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/cassandra/docs/2.0.3.RELEASE/reference/html/#core.extensions.querydsl. ReactiveCassandraTemplate can be used with the driver's QueryBuilder

Comment: However I don't like to use the field name "hard-coded" on the where clause though.